# JSENCODE is not working when used with global variable like ($Label) in javascript

Tags: visualforce

In our application we are defining custom labels and we are trying to access the value in JavaScript section of the visualforce page. But looks like JSENCODE function is not encoding the characters as expected.

The custom label name is "END_OF_TERM" and we have defined the label text as "End' of Term" for testing purpose.

The JavaScript code is like this.

```
var endOfTerm = '{!JSENCODE($Label.END_OF_TERM)}';
```

After rendering the value we see is as `'End' of Term'`. Which shows that the single quote inside the text is not encoded. We tried with other characters like double quote but have the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `HTMLENCODE` or `JSINHTMLENCODE` as well?

Comment: Yes I tried both now. But I am seeing the same result. Not working.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Maybe try `var endOfTerm = \`{!$Label.END_OF_TERM}\`;` The backtick (`\``) has different rules that might help in this case.

Comment: Funny thing is it works when you use it in Visualforce instead of JavaScript, maybe if you are in JavaScript you have to use JavaScript Encoding? which sounds silly!

Comment: Using any other character like (") or (`) may work for handling single quote, but it will break again when the same character is add to the label. So it is not the ideal solution. Main issue is why JSENCODE is not encoding when used in context with global variable.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use a hidden input field in VF page, fetch its value in  JavaScript. Definitely a bug as sfdcfox has mentioned.